# Visual Studio, MonoGame integration issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, monogame

I installed monogame from there site, the 3.4 version for Visual Studio as it's the version specified for a course I'm taking. I already had the most recent version of Visual Studio 2015 community edition installed for use with unity. Something potentially important to note is that VS is installed on my (f) hardrive where as monogame autamtically installs onto the (C) boot drive where my windows is, I also installed windows SDK there. I don't have enough space on the boot drive for VS and Unity.

The install seemed to go fine, but no monogame templates show up within Visual studio itself when I try and crate a new project. I found them in the directory in documents, so they did install,(F:\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#\MonoGame) and nothing in itemtemplates, though copying it over to item templates didn't do anything. So, for some reason they aren't showing up in Visual Studio and they really need to in order to have any use.

Anyone have suggestions/solutions? I've reinstalled monogame multiple times and am very reluctant to reinstall VS.

Comment: MonoGame 3.5 worked fine immediately... only problem is the course specifies 3.4 not 3.5. Guess I'll just go through it with 3.5 and hope no problems arise caused by the difference in versions.

Comment: There where lots of bug fixes and improvements between 3.4 and 3.5. I'd be surprised if you ran into problems though. In my experience, 3.5 is much more stable. Btw.. if you've answered your own question you can (and should) write an answer and accept it on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a number of things, including suggested solutions on these forums and nothing seemed to have any effect as nothing would appear under templates within VS. I finally just installed MonoGame 3.5 and it worked fine immediately... I've been doing the course with 3.5 and have ran into no problems so far, but admittedly I haven't gotten to the part which makes use of MonoGame yet....